# How to pass diferent kind of parameters to .Net 5 web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net5

I am creating a .NET 5 Web API, I have my controller with two methods, the first one is a Get method like this:

```cs
[Route("GetRankingByListIdAll/{ListId}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetRankingByListIdAll([FromQuery] string ListId)
{
    var result = await _userService.GetRankingByListIdAll(ListId);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

The other method is a `POST` method like this:

```cs
[HttpPost("AddUser")]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddUser([FromBody] Model model)
{
    bool userInList = await _usersService.validateEmailInUsers(model.email, model.otherProperty);
    if (!userInList)
    {
        var result = await _userService.addUser(model.property, model.otherProperty,model.proper);
        return Ok(result);
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest("message");
    }
}
```

As you can see in the get method I put "[Route]" to set the route and in the post method I put the route in the [HttpPost("")], but I cant pass the parameters, I have tried in the Get method using the route like this:
`[HttpGet("GetRankingByListIdAll/{ListId}")]`
but it does not work either
in the Get method I am using this request:
https://localhost:44340/api/User/GetUserByListId/ListId=59D512FB-1CCF-47E2-8E85-B4F76192D941
my controller is called "UserController" and my api has authoeization using JWT
in .net core 2.2 this API works fine, but I have not found how to do it in .net 5, I was wondering if anyone could helping me.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 2):

Very little has changed in .Net 5 regarding REST API with Attribute routing i.  I highly suggest going over the following:

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

[Create a REST API with Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing).

There are no mentions of changes:

[Breaking changes in .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/5.0)

For a route configured as the following

```
[HttpGet("GetRankingByListIdAll/{ListId}")]
```

Your http request should appear as

```
/GetUserByListId/59D512FB-1CCF-47E2-8E85-B4F76192D941
```

You should not specify the parameter name in the url.  Since the parameter is *not* from the *querystring* you should not specify `[FromQuery]` either.

```
[Route("GetRankingByListIdAll/{ListId}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetRankingByListIdAll(string ListId)
{
  //....
}
```

And for clarification the Url:

```
https:∕∕www.mydomain.com∕a∕b∕c∕1∕2∕3?z=1&b=2#tag
```

Is brokendown as:

```
Scheme: https          //before the colon (:)
host: www              //before the first period (.)
domain: mydomain.com   //before the first slash (/)
path: /a/b/c/1/2/3     //before the question mark (?)
querystring: z=1&b=2   //before the hash/pound symbol (#)
fragment: tag          //after the hash/pound symbol
```

(Generally speaking)

Answer (score 2):

> As you can see in the get method I put "[Route]" to set the route and
> in the post method I put the route in the [HttpPost("")], but I cant
> pass the parameters, I have tried in the Get method using the route
> like this: [HttpGet("GetRankingByListIdAll/{ListId}")] but it does not
> work either in the Get method I am using this request:
> https://localhost:44340/api/User/GetUserByListId/ListId=59D512FB-1CCF-47E2-8E85-B4F76192D941
> my controller is called "UserController" and my api has authoeization
> using JWT in .net core 2.2 this API works fine, but I have not found
> how to do it in .net 5, I was wondering if anyone could helping me.
>
> ```
> [HttpGet("GetRankingByListIdAll/{ListId}")]
>
> [Route("GetRankingByListIdAll/{ListId}")]
> ```

When you use the `Route` attribute and the `HttpGet` method as the above, since the parameter is transferred from the route, so if you are using `[FormBody]` attribute in the Get method, you can't get the value.

To solve this issue, use the `[FromRoute]` attribute, code as below:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetRankingByListIdAll/{ListId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetRankingByListIdAll([FromRoute] string ListId)
    {
        var result = "Entered Id: " + ListId;
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Then, use PostMan to check it, the result as below:

[image]

And if you are using JQuery to call the API method, the code like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Call Get Method" id="btnGet" />
<input type="button" value="Call Post Method" id="btnPost" />

<div id="result"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#btnGet").click(function () {
            var listid = "Num1002";
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/ToDo/GetRankingByListIdAll/" + listid, //The url like this: https://localhost:44355/api/ToDo/GetRankingByListIdAll/NV1003
                method: "Get", 
                success: function (res) {
                    $("#result").html(res);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        });
        $("#btnPost").click(function () {
            var user = {};
            user.UserId = 1002;
            user.UserName = "Tom";

            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/ToDo/AddUser",   //the url like this:https://localhost:44355/api/ToDo/AddUser
                method: "Post",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                traditional: true, //if the user object is a complex objects, try to add this attribute.
                data: JSON.stringify(user),
                success: function (res) {
                    $("#result").html(res);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The result as below:

[image]